# Sharing Components between 2 projects while retaining hot reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, npm

We are developing 2 products using Angular 2 (although it would be the same problem for React).  We would like to share components between the 2 products.  I was thinking that breaking things up into npm modules would be a good way to achieve that.

The issue is that making code changes will become a problem and really slow down the development process.

Can anyone suggest a way of keeping this separation, but also be able to see changes straight away on browser refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question - this can be done by using [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)

npm link allows you to have a link in each of the 2 client projects to the shared module.

In the shared module's source folder (with the package.json in it): -

```
npm link
```

This creates a global link for the package name in the package.json file (e.g. my-shared-module)

Then in each of the client projects: -

```
npm link my-shared-module
```

This will make a symbolic link in your node_modules folder (which can be monitored for changes by your build system)